# POST REST Service does not respond to my ajax jquery call (GET yes, it does)

Tags: java, ajax, rest, jersey

I have got a simple rest server by jersey (java) with web interface that use jquery. I have a REST Service for GET and POST mode. The POST call does not work, it has a json object in input data side and return a json data.

Exception message:

```
A message body reader for Java class ....RESTTaskDataInput, and Java type class ....RESTTaskDataInput, and MIME media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 was not found.

The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:

application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider...
```

Jquery code for post call (a click button does the call):

```
        $("#task-launcher-post").click(function()
        {                
            $("div#result").text(""); 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",                    
                url: "resources/foo", <= This is OK, the rest interface is under that
                data: {
                    code: "1234",
                    email: "my@email.com"
                },
                dataType: "json",                    
                success: function(result)
                {   
                    $("div#result").append('...');
                },
                error: function(xml,result)
                {
                    $("div#result").append('...');                    
                }
            });                                            
        });
```

Java REST Service code

```
@Path("/foo")
public class RESTSERVICECrawler 
{
   ...

   @POST    
   @Consumes("application/json")
   @Produces("application/json")
   public RESTLaunchResult launch(RESTTaskDataInput input) 
   {                
      RESTLaunchResult result = new RESTLaunchResult();
      ...
      return result;
   }
```

}

Java RESTTaskDataInput code (data used in input side)

```
@XmlRootElement
public class RESTTaskDataInput 
{ 
   public String code;    
   public String email;        
}
```

A GET call works with url parameters, but POST does not with json in the input. I dont know why, i read jquery documentation of ajax, I think that rest server cannot understand the json input data.

Comment: Your AJAX request isn't sending JSON, rather it's sending the POST data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Thank you. That is correct. I will put the solution in new awnser.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public RESTLaunchResult launch(JAXBElement<RESTTaskDataInput> input)  {
    try {
        RESTTaskDataInput data = input.getValue();
    } ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution thank to Charlie indication. Is needed to set the contentType.

```
                var data = {
                   code: "123",
                   email: "email"
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",                    
                    url: "resources/foo",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: "json",         
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(result)
                    {   
                        $("div#result").append('<h5 id="result" class="text-success">' + result.success + " " + result.message + '</h5></div>');
                    },
                    error: function(xml,result)
                    {
                        $("div#result").append('<h5 id="result" class="text-error">' + result + '</h5>');     
                    }
                });
```